# Android remove current fragment and get removed fragment name

Tags: android, fragment

I want remove fragment and get name of removed fragment.

I have used fragmentManager.popBackStack(); for remove fragment but 
want name of removed fragment as well

Please help me for this

Comment: You need to get fragment name before popbackstack. it is not possible after pobackstack call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Fragment name from BackStackEntry before remove

Check This,

```
 FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
            Log.e(TAG, "clearBackStack: " + first.getName());
            manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        }
```

Comment: The documentation says that the entry at index 0 is the one at the bottom o the stack. Doesn't that mean that the one that will be popped is at position "<size of the stack> - 1"?